# Struggling to make a canvas with a bitmap and draw on it

Tags: android, canvas

Here's my code thus far. 
EDIT: Added full code.

```
public void enterPreviewMode(byte[] pictureData) {

    //Stop preview and enter review mode
    previewPic = true;
    cam.stopPreview();

    //Find buttons and make them visible/invisible
    Button takePicB = (Button)findViewById(R.id.takePicButton);
    Button exitPreviewB = (Button)findViewById(R.id.xButton);
    exitPreviewB.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    exitPreviewB.setEnabled(true);
    takePicB.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    takePicB.setEnabled(false);

    //Decode byte array into bmp image, then copy bmp to make drawable for canvas
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(pictureData, 0, pictureData.length);
    Bitmap drawableBmp = bmp.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

    //Find ImageView, make it fit the screen, set the image (and rotate the image), set visible
    ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.picPreview);
    image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    image.setImageBitmap(rb.RotateBitmap(drawableBmp,90));
    image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    //Create canvas using drawableBmp, currently fills in black for testing purposes
    Canvas editableZone = new Canvas(drawableBmp);
    editableZone.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
}
```

This is my attempt to take a picture, and draw on it (well, just put a rectangle on it for now, baby steps). Sadly, nothing shows up on the image with this code. Tried reading over some tutorials for my specific situation and can't seem to recognize where I went wrong.

Comment: What parameters does `drawRect ()` take? You are likely making a rectangle with no width or height.

Comment: @BenyamEphrem drawRect takes (float left, float right, float top, float bottom, Paint)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Problem was that my rotateBMP function created a new bmp, oops.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem on this code:editableZone.drawRect(100f,100f,100f,100f,p),
for the drawRect(float left, float top, float right, float bottom, Paint paint);
and you can try this one editableZone.drawRect(100f,100f,200f,200f,p)

Good luck

Comment: Tried changing top and bottom to 200f, but no luck :/

Comment: Dimensions are correct but for the paint value pass in `0x0000FF` (it'll be blue)

Comment: @BenyamEphrem Just tried, says it needs a Paint value and recieved an Int

Comment: so, can you see the bitmap? or you can see nothing?

Comment: @jtxyz0804 I can see the bitmap, but nothing is drawn on it. I put the drawableBMP on an ImageView, not sure if that complicates things

Comment: I using the follow code and it can draw the rect on the bitmap

Comment: is drawableBmp larger than 100x100 pixels?  It's possible you're drawing the rect outside of the canvas dimensions.

Comment: @ripple182 Tested this by using drawColor(Color.BLACK), nothing happened :/ added more code and comments in OP

Answer (score 0):

```
    I using the follow code and it can draw the rect on the bitmap 

public Bitmap getRectBitmap(){
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.new_home_default_editor_portrait);
            Bitmap copyBitmap = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
            int w = copyBitmap.getWidth();
            int h = copyBitmap.getHeight();

            Bitmap tem = Bitmap.createBitmap(copyBitmap, 0, 0, w, h);
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(tem);
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setColor(Color.RED);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(10f);
            canvas.drawRect(10f, 10f, 200f, 200f, paint);

            return tem;
        }
```

Comment: Still not working for me, heres my full code. Oops, guess I can't put that here, will add to OP